# How do you define Flow types for Redux Actions?

Tags: javascript, redux, flowtype

I'm working through methods of typing Redux actions with Flow. Using the following definitions it is partially working in both the action creator and the reducer. Autocomplete picks up all 4 actions as possible values for `action.type` in both locations.

```
// @flow
type ModuleActionTypes1 = 'moduleOne/ACTION_ONE' | 'moduleOne/ACTION_TWO';
type ModuleActionTypes2 = 'moduleTwo/ACTION_ONE' | 'moduleTwo/ACTION_TWO';

type ActionTypes = ModuleActionTypes1 | ModuleActionTypes2;

type Action<T> = {
  type: ActionTypes,
  payload: T
};

type Payload = {
  url: string
};

const actionCreator = (url: string): Action<Payload> => {
  return {
    type: 'moduleOne/ACTION_ONE',
    payload: {
      url: url
    }
  };
};

const reducer = (state: string, action: Action<Payload>): string => {

  if(action.type === 'wrong') {
    // action.type cannot be this 
  }

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'moduleOne/ACTION_ONE':
    case 'wrong': // action type cannot be this
      const { url } = action.payload;
      return url;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

It almost does what I want. There are two main issues:

1. The switch cases don't have to be one of `action.type`, so typos could slip through. This suggests I should stick with string constants.
2. When I `import type { ModuleActionTypes1 } from '../moduleOne';` (instead of defining it in the same file for testing) autocomplete stops working but flow reports no errors on the command line. All the files contain the @flow comment.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

So, it's a little different from your question, but let me suggest doing this a little differently. Right now, your action type says that any payload can belong to any action. Flow can be a lot more helpful if you use your types to define only allowable states.

I don't know what your actions do, so here is a random example:

```
type CreatePerson = { type: 'create-person', person: Person };
type DestroyPerson = { type: 'destroy-person', personId: number };
type ChangePersonName = { type: 'change-name', personId: number, name: string }
type PersonActions = CreatePerson | DestroyPerson | ChangePersonName
```

Setting it up this way helps ensure that each Redux action has the right data in the right types. In your reducer, you can still do a switch/if on `action.type` to pick which case to use. But now, by picking out the type by string, Flow also knows exactly what type of data exists on the action. This can let you avoid casting or unsafe destructuring that Flow can't type check.

Comment: Thanks for the response. While this does seem a little simpler it still suffers from a similar issue. If I get the action.type correct in the switch case the payload is typed correctly and errors are highlighted. If I typo the action.type the payload gets typed as `any` and no errors are reported. This is inferior to just using string constants.

Comment: What I'm aiming for is knowledge that a reducer is checking for an `action.type` that doesn't exist, so is likely wrong.

Comment: I notice that this code works as expected:

```type AorB = 'a' | 'b';

const reducer = (state: string, action: AorB) => {
  if(action === 'wrong') {
    // action.type cannot be this 
  }
};``` so there must be something about it being a property on a wrapping object that removes the enum checking?

Comment: Yep, it looks like that's it. Your string version works fine, but the same thing except using an object with a type property does not: `type AorB = { type: 'a' } | { type: 'b' }; const reducer = (state: string, action: AorB) => { if (action.type === 'wrong') {}};`